# MariaDB Remote machine Data at rest encryption

Tags: mariadb, encryption

I'm work on setting up a MariaDB local instance on  laptops that will spend most of their time disconnected/unable to connect to the internet.

One of the requirements of the project is to encrypt the local instance of the data. which is hosted on a central server and replicated out to individual nodes when they reconnect to the internet.

I have set up MariaDB's Data at rest encryption using the file key management plugin  but it's a little disconcerting that the keyfile is available on the local machine. What alternatives are available; besides having the front end app encrypt the data before inserting it into the db?

Comment: I think a better way to address this requirement is full disk encryption on the mobile workstations.

Comment: That's something we're looking into.  I'm just trying to sort out some potential fall back options if full disk encryption isn't an option.

Comment: You can mount `/var/lib/mysql/ ` on an encrypted filesystem and leave `/` unencrypted.

Comment: Full disk encryption was standard policy at the company I worked for a few years ago.  The IT folks seemed to have no problem with it.  You will _also_ need SSL and/or VPN when syncing.  Get it done fast; Potus seems headed for outlawing such.